# python не хочет выводить строку через пробел

Tags: python, print

Нужно , чтобы зверюшки выводились не вниз, а рядом - справа, не могу понять как это реализовать? Из дополнительных функций можно использовать только sep, end.
Мой код:

```
number = 2
n=''' 
   _~_    
  (o o)   
 /  V  \  
/(  _  )\ 
  ^^ ^^ '''
print(n*number, )
```

Answer (score 1):

Пингвин весь находится в одной строке, а когда вы ее выводите, она выводится последовательно. Я предлагаю следующий код со списками. Его можно преобразовать в код с переменными:

```
number = 2

n=''' 
   _~_    
  (o o)   
 /  V  \  
/(  _  )\ 
  ^^ ^^ '''
list_lines = n.split('\n')  # разбиваем пингвина на строки по символу новой строки
for i in list_lines:
    print(i*number)  # выводим их
```

Comment: если писать код без цикла, то нужно создавать 5 переменных?

Comment: number = 2
a='   _~_'
b='  (o o)'
c=' /  V  \\'
d='/(  _  )\\'
f='  ^^ ^^'

print(a,b,c,d,f, sep='\n')   Не понимаю как умножать пингвинов тепреь

Comment: @formanite да, нужно 5 переменных, где будут содержаться строки 
`print(a*number, b*number, c*number, d*number, f*number, sep='\n')`
Python может умножать строку на число. Например, 'a'*5 = 'aaaaa'. Тут в вас именно это

Comment: умножаю теперь каждую переменную на number и он все в одну трочку выводит

Comment: @formanite а sep='\n' не забыли?

Comment: Все, там нужно еще в каждой строчке несколько пробелов поставить, разобрался)

Comment: @formanite тогда отметьте ответ как верный